# How to setup docker in read_only mode in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Many guides shows, it is good to make the container in read_only mode.

However, how to do this in docker-compose?
Many containers save logs at least, so they need r+w permission.

How do you setup containter in read_only mode? None of my solutions founded on the net worked.

Please, answer if you setup this on your server and know which solution works.

Comment: `None of my solutions founded on the net worked` which ones? \

Answer (score 4):

You can set a container to read only mode in compose with the [read_only](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir) key for a given service:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    read_only: true
    command: sleep 999
```

This effectively removes the container's write layer, which means you'll get a `Read-only file system` error if any process attempts to write to the container`s filesystem.

If you are an image author, you certainly need to take this into account. Any location that the containerized software expects to be able to write to should be mounted as a volume. The image author should mark every such location in the Dockerfile using the `VOLUME` instruction. When the resulting container image runs, an anonymous volume will be attached at that location in read-write mode. At runtime, you can specify a named volume or bind mount at that same location if an anonymous volume is not appropriate.

The example you gave for a read/write usecase is logging. Docker includes its own [logging subsystem](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/) that treats the stdout/stderr of the main process in the container as a log stream. This works even with the container in read-only mode, so configure your application to write its logs that way.

Other examples of a read-write requirement in a container is a database or any other system that wants to persist data to disk. That data should go into a volume instead of on the container's filesystem whether or not you utilize the `read_only` feature.

Comment: As far as I understood the documentation you provided, this doesn't apply to the container but rather the other way around, the volume

Comment: @GuiTaek There is a `read_only` for a long syntax volume stanza and a `read_only` for the service itself. The one I linked was the latter, although I'm not sure why the docs put the `domainname, hostname, ipc, mac_address, privileged, read_only, shm_size, stdin_open, tty, user, working_dir` section underneath the `volumes` section. The `read_only` I'm referring to does apply to the container. "Each of these is a single value, analogous to its docker run counterpart."